# Java Change Date Format

Tags: java, date, format

I want to change my Date object format. I looked other topics but always Date converted to String. I have this one:

```
String datee=unitdata[i].toString();
Date dater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(datee);
String smp= new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(dater);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
Date date = df.parse(smp);
x[i]=date;
```

date returned like this: `"Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 CET 1970`",
but I want like this: "`01`" in Date format **not String**.

Thanks

Comment: `Date` objects don't have a format. Formatting can only be applied when you display it as a string.

Comment: @forgivenson so I can't do something thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date objects don't have a format. Formatting can only be applied when you display them as a strings. A Date object simply stores all the info about the date (day, month, year, time, etc). When displaying that data, it is displayed as a string, and that is when it makes sense to arrange the data in a specific format.

As for outputting the format you mentioned, you can use a format of "dd" (since you just want the date, with leading zero if needed).